# jq: populate object bedides of field exists

Tags: jq

I'm using this filter in:

```
map({
    name,
    deceased: (.deceased? // empty | split(" ") | first | strptime("%Y/%m/%d") | strftime("%F"))
})
```

input objects are:

```json
{
    "name": "name1",
    "birth": "1950/05/05",
    "deceased": "1982/05/19"
}
{
    "name": "name2",
    "birth": "1982/05/19"
}
```

I'm getting:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "name1",
    "deceased": "1982-05-19"
  }
]
```

I need to get:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "name1",
    "deceased": "1982-05-19"
  },
  {
    "name": "name2"
  }
]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What does “bedides” signify?

Comment: This is exactly the same question as your previous one, just with different names

Comment: Re "*I'm getting*", You're getting nothing for the second because you pruned that value from the stream by using `empty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test for existence using `has`

```
map(
  {name} +
  if has("deceased")
  then {deceased: (.deceased | strptime("%Y/%m/%d") | strftime("%F"))}
  else {}
  end
)
```

```json
[
  {
    "name": "name1",
    "deceased": "1982-05-19"
  },
  {
    "name": "name2"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/TudrdlDcOg)

---

If `.deceased` can only exist as string, then this would be equivalent:

```
map(
  {name, deceased}
  | .deceased |= (strings | strptime("%Y/%m/%d") | strftime("%F"))
)
```

```json
[
  {
    "name": "name1",
    "deceased": "1982-05-19"
  },
  {
    "name": "name2"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/2mckWjHrri)